# Is this device authentication method (using AES-256) secure?

Tags: aes, authentication, key-size

Let's say we have:

- `client_id_ran`: 256 bit random text (chosen only once for whole system) used to generate `client_id` by incrementing 1 for each client.
- `challenge_ran`: 256 bit random text (chosen only once for whole system) used to generate `challenge_plain_text` by incrementing 1 for subsequent authentication requests.
- `challenge_plain_text`: generated from `challenge_ran` as specified above.
- `client_id`: generated from `client_id_ran` as specified above.
- `server_secrect_key`: random 256 bit text
- `client_secrect_key`: pre-shared / configured at industry to `AES256(ENCRYPT,server_secrect_key, client_id);`

Authentication procedure:

1. client request for `challenge_plain_text` by `sending client_id`
2. Server response with the `AES256(ENCRYPT,client_secrect_key, challenge_plain_text);`
3. client decrypts the massage by `client_secrect_key` to get `challenge_plain_text`
4. client encrypts the `challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one` with the `client_secrect_key` and send back to the server. i.e, `AES256(ENCRYPT, client_secrect_key, challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one);`
5. server decrypts the `encrypted_challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one` by generating `client_secrect_key` from `client_id`. `if(decrypted_challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one == challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one && response_time<=4000ms`), client authenticated else connection closed.

AES_ECB mode is used for encryption & decryption of 256bit texts. Hence `challenge_plain_text_increamented_by_one` should be achieved by incrementing each 128bit part of 256bit text by one.

The proposed plan is for authenticating IoT devices where we can save the `client_id` & `client_secrect_key` to the device before delivering to the customer.

Comment: AES is a 128 bit block cipher, it is not defined for input other than 128 bits. Usually a MAC is used instead of the block cipher itself for these kind of purposes.

Comment: We're cryptographers, it's our job **not** to ignore the little things. You've just published a draft *to us*, can we please expect it to be written to the best of your abilities? Yes, the block size is 128 bits. So how do you define `AES256(client_secrect_key, challenge_plain_text, ENCRYPT)` if `challenge_plain_text` is 256 bits?

Comment: As mentioned by SEJPM, a MITM could just pass the authentication data unchanged, and then modify the application data at will.  Because of this, there has to be some cryptographical binding (e.g. encryption/MAC keys) between the authentication and the rest of the exchange...

Answer (score 1):

If the goal of this protocol is to authenticate the user, then it falls rather easily to a man in the middle attack.

Concretely:

- By passively sniffing on the real server's traffic figure out the current value of `challenge_plain_text`.
- Impersonate the server.
- As soon as you get a request from any client, accept it and record the client ID.
- Send a `challenge_plain_text` back to the client which you expect to be used soon by the real server.
- Receive the encryption of said challenge from the client, you may now ignore the client or fake successful authentication.
- Now to impersonate the client from whom you just got the response to the challenge wait for the moment where the next authentication will use the `challenge_plain_text` you used.
- Now claim to be said client and request authentication.
- You will get the `challenge_plain_text` for which you have the answer, respond with it and be authenticated.

This works as all the values are easily *predictable*. A rather simply mitigation would be for the server to always pick a fresh random value for each authentication request. But then still the attacker could perform a [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and "authenticate" as the client thinking the attacker is the server to the real server by doing a simple pass-through of all messages.

Comment: Other mitigations: somehow including the ID in the challenge (use a MAC to extend input range) or even better: using different keys for client and server.

Comment: @DebabrataMandal I don't have time for a proper explanation now, bnut will probably provide one within 24h (if not ping me again). The short version is that for the second mitm attack the attacker will behave like any server en-route of the data packets and just modify the metadata to claim it's them who is requesting authentication but still forwarding everything. Mitigations against this are more difficult. The 4s timelimit should be no problem for any of the attacks.

Comment: @DebabrataMandal well for that one, remember that the attacker picked a `challenge_plain_text` from the future, so they observe the current authentication requests to and from the server and as soon as the the one for which the attacker already has an answer is next, they request authentication and use the saved data.

Comment: As for your previous comment, the idea is that the attacker knows that these values are incremented, thus they pick a value of eg +50 when they impersonate the server to the client and then after 49 new requests to the server they have their chosen `challenge_plain_text` is next and they can successfully resend the saved messages.

Comment: Sorry, out of time for today. This starts to look at full crypto design, which is off topic here - questions, answers and comments would go on for pages. Maybe somebody on "the side channel" chat is willing to help (but don't get nasty if they don't).

Comment: @DebabrataMandal I would indeed strongly recommend you to just use TLS 1.2 or 1.3 with the pre-shared key ciphersuites / handshake if possible.